# xcode build error Property 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' not found on object of type 'FIRFirestoreSettings *

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I'm getting the following error while building XCode:

xcode build error Property 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' not found on object of type 'FIRFirestoreSettings *'

Whithin RNFirebaseFirestore.m the rows in error:
if (settings[@"timestampsInSnapshots"]) {
firestoreSettings.timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = settings[@"timestampsInSnapshots"];
}

system to reproduce:

"react-native": "^0.64.0"
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.4.1",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.4.1",
XCode 12.5

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I recall correctly the `timestampsInSnapshots` setting was removed a few years ago. You might want to update your dependencies, or remove the code that tries to access to.

Comment: Hello @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your reply. Actually it seems those are the most updated dependencies, therefore I don't understand why they're still using timestampsInSnapshots, even if you're probably right. On the other hand I'm not sure which could be the impact by removing the code :-| Maybe I'll try to downgrade those...

Comment: I'm having the same issue, all dependencies are updated to the latest. @ste471 any luck getting a successful build?

Comment: @hugger we're two now! Not yet

Comment: getting same issue, all dependencies are updated and also tried to update pod and clean pod cache...Any solution?

Comment: @SurbhiDavara I as well, I've tried already to delete all pods, cleaned pod cache, cleaned build, cleaned derived data, deleted all node-modules, reinstalled node-modules via npm, pod install... and again same error (as in the subject of this question) coming from the file RNFirebaseFirestore.m. I've also checked

Comment: @SurbhiDavara I've also checked on https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js and in reality on version 8.0.0  Oct 26,2020 they have announced 'Breaking change: Removed the timestampsInSnapshots option from FirestoreSettings. Now, Cloud Firestore always returns Timestamp values for all timestamp values.'  And actually if you look here 'https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FirestoreSettings' there isn't anymore the class 'timestampsInSnapshots.

Comment: I've also opened an issue ticket to the support of Firebase... let's see :-(

Comment: @benrudhart I've experienced a type of error on Xcode 12.5 similar to yours, which refers again to Firestore (see below). Would you be able to help us? Many thanks

Comment: @ste471 are you using react-native-firebase package? Because I did mistake that using that package after I removed this package it's working properly!!

Comment: @SurbhiDavara yes I do use react-native-firebase package, but the strange thing is that before it run! Now if I need to remove it whatelse should I use for the database of the app?

Comment: @ste471 please remove react-native-firebase package because if you are using firestore for database so don't need it and as you can see that firestore have updated RNfirebaseFirestore.m file but at last one year react-native-firebase not updated package that's why getting this error!!

Comment: @SurbhiDavara yes done & resolved! thanks so much! I had duplicated react-native-firebase/app and react-native-firebase and I've removed only this last one :-)

Comment: Yea by removing the react native firebase package it solved the problem to me as well! Thanks!